# Time is not continuous

Tags: python, time, matplotlib

For the piece of code which is below produces time only in the starting and ending of the graph meaning it is displaying initial time as 00:00 and final time as 15:00 (not displaying middle values) but the time is not continuous. I want the middle time as well, meaning 0:00 1:00 2:00 3:00 4:00 5:00 till 15:00. How to make it continuous time series.

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax1=ax.twiny()
    ax.plot(self.flttime1,smoothListGaussian(self.fLaZ1),'b-', label='Z axis (Left Smoothed)')
    self.npfLaZ=(np.array(self.fLaZ1)+[0.6])
    ax.plot(self.flttime1,(smoothListGaussian(self.npfLaZ)),'g-', label='Z axis (Left Smoothed)')

    hfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%M:%S')

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.SecondLocator())
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
    ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.SecondLocator())
    ax1.set_xlim(dt.datetime(2000, 12, 5,0,0,0) ,dt.datetime(2007, 12, 5,0,15,0))
    ax1.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%M:%S')
    ax.grid(True)
    plt.legend(loc=2)
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

Then after the line:

```
ax1.set_xlim(dt.datetime(2000, 12, 5,0,0,0) ,dt.datetime(2007, 12, 5,0,15,0))
```

Add :

```
ax1.set_xticks([pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2000, 12, 5,0,0,0), end=dt.datetime(2007, 12, 5,0,15,0), freq="1min")])
```

Since I dont have ur dataset, check whether this is working.

Comment: It is showing me an error as 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xticks'